# get value of last child and the next 3 child

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid">
    <div class="ad_box col-md-11">
        <input type="hidden" class="paged" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" class="posts_per_page" value="3">
        <input type="hidden" class="offset" value="0">
    </div>
    <div class="ad_box col-md-11">
        <input type="hidden" class="paged" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" class="posts_per_page" value="3">
        <input type="hidden" class="offset" value="0">
    </div>
    <div class="ad_box col-md-11">
        <input type="hidden" class="paged" value="5">
        <input type="hidden" class="posts_per_page" value="5">
        <input type="hidden" class="offset" value="5">
    </div>
</div>
```

Hi, i have something like this
Now i need to grab the laste 3 value 5,5,5
How do this?

Comment: Try using JQuery or just JavaScript to select the elements and get there values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just off the top of my head using basic javascript...

```
var Ads = document.getElementsByClassName("ad_box");
var Elem = Ads[2];  //get the last Div
var val1 = Elem.childNodes[0].value;
var val2 = Elem.childNodes[1].value;
var val3 = Elem.childNodes[2].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start by doing something like this to get your parent element

```
$('.vc_row')
```

Then there are a few ways to get your last child, heres one

```
$('.vc_row').find('.ad_box:last-child')
```

That will give you your object, then you can find its value or it's elements' values

```
// get its value
$('.vc_row).find('.ad_box:last-child').val()

// get something from its children
$('.vc_row).find('.ad_box:last-child').find('selector').val()
```